# How to get the data in nodejs console to html

Tags: node.js, api, pug, backend

I am using smartapi provided by angelbroking.

I want to make a stock ticker which can display realtime price of stocks like this one

https://www.tickertape.in/screener?utm_source=gads&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=screener&gclid=Cj0KCQiA8ICOBhDmARIsAEGI6o1xfYgsbvDEB6c2OFTEYRp9e5UDnJxgCyBJJphdKTduZ_EOHCAchpoaAp-WEALw_wcB

I am able to connect to websocket using the sdk provided in documentation but I don't know how to display that data in my html page.

Please suggest if you know how to get the json data from nodejs console to html.

The nodejs code is

```
let { SmartAPI, WebSocket } = require("smartapi-javascript");


let web_socket = new WebSocket({
    client_code: "P529774",
    feed_token: "0973308957"
});

web_socket.connect()
    .then(() => {
        web_socket.runScript("nse_cm|2885", "cn") // SCRIPT: nse_cm|2885, mcx_fo|222900  TASK: mw|sfi|dp
        web_socket.runScript("nse_cm|2885", "mw")
            /*setTimeout(function() {
                web_socket.close()
            }, 60000)*/
    })

web_socket.on('tick', receiveTick)


function receiveTick(data) {
    console.log("receiveTick:::::", data)
}
```

The response I get is similar to this :

```
[{"ak":"ok","task":"mw","msg":"mw"}]
 [{"lo":"1797.55","ts":"ACC-EQ","tp":null,"ltp":"1800.05","ltq":"27","bs":"16","tk":"22","ltt":"31\/08\/2017 11:32:01",
 "lcl":null,"tsq":"76435","cng":"-11.15","bp":"1800.00","bq":"510","mc":"34012.01277(Crs)","isdc":"18.77872
 (Crs)","name":"sf","tbq":"76497","oi":null,"yh":"1801.25","e":"nse_cm","sp":"1800.90","op":"1814.00","c": "1811.20",
 "to":"145093696.35","ut":"31-Aug-2017 11:32:01","h":"1817.55","v":"80391","nc":"- 00.62","ap":"1804.85","yl":"1800.00","ucl":null,"toi":"16654000" }]
```

The github repo for smartapi nodejs
https://github.com/angelbroking-github/smartapi-javascript

The API Docs
https://smartapi.angelbroking.com/docs/Introduction

Comment: We will need more  info to help you out with this. How does your frontend talk with your backend? Do you have a websocket / REST API / Html templating system? Are you using any HTTP server libraries like Express.js?

Comment: Actually my frontend for now is nothing much but a marquee tag from which I am planning to make the stock ticker. I used this code from the sdk provided in the github repo above. It provides me data on the basis by adding different scripts like the one "nse_cm|2885". But the problem I have now is to display the data in html. I am a total beginner with nodejs so I don't have an idea how will I send the data from nodejs to html cause there is no option like to use getElementById in node.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, here's two:

**Cache the last message + HTTP polling**

This is not the most efficient solution, but perhaps the simplest. Each time your recieveTick() callback hits, you could save the response message in a global object / collection (cache it). Better yet, you could pre-process the message and therefore just cache whatever info you actually care about in that global collection and save bandwidth on the connection between your frontend HTML and backend.

Then, add an HTTP endpoint to your backend that serves up the last info relevant to a given ticker. You could  use Express.js or some other simple HTTP server library. That way when your frontend calls

```
http://<backend_host>:<backend_port>/tickers/<ticker>
```

Your backend will read from the cached data and serve up the needed data.

**Create your own websocket and forward the data**

This is a better solution, specially if your data providers API has a quick (subsecond) refresh rate. Create your own websocket server that will make a websocket connection with your frontend. Then, when you get a message from the data providers websocket, simply processes it in whatever way you would like (to get it into the format your frontend wants) then forward it to the frontend by using your websocket server. This will also be done within the recieveTick() function.

There are many websocket tools for nodejs. For help with the websocket stuff check this out https://ably.com/blog/web-app-websockets-nodejs

Also just a quick note, in your question you said "...how to get the json data from nodejs console to html". This kind of suggests that you would like to write the data to the console, and then read it from the  console to html. This isn't the way you should think about it. The console was one destination, and the html is another, both originating from the websocket callback.

Comment: How will I " forward the websocket to the frontend by using your websocket server " the data from the websocket to html ?

Comment: The question arises because I am already getting the json data from api provider using a websocket and it can just be displayed in the console and not anywhere else. So how will making another websocket and display the data on html ?

Comment: A Node.js application is a backend application, it runs on a server and not in the browser. This is a significant difference from browser JS. Because of this, it has no way of directly accessing or manipulating the DOM, or document object (or HTML) in the browser. So generally your options are either to insert your data into the HTML before you send that HTML to the browser, or establish some form of communication between the back and front end, as described in the post above.

Comment: Your browser JS will need to make an API call to your backend, either with HTTP or Websockets, then it will receive the data on the frontend and therefore be able to use document.getElementByID() for example and insert the new data. You need to do some research. Look into REST API's, Websocket server and client libraries for Nodejs and the browser.